# Symmetric $\mathbb F_2$-bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$K$ is a field with $2^d$ elements. $K^*$ is a cyclic group generated by $\alpha$ and $T:K\rightarrow \mathbb F_2$ is a non-zero $\mathbb F_2$ linear map.

Can you help me proving that the symmetric $\mathbb F_2$-bilinear form $K\times K\rightarrow \mathbb F_2: (x,y)\rightarrow T(xy)$ is non-degenerate, i.e $T(xy)=0$ for all $y\in K$ implies $x=0$

I do not see how this follows following the properties of the bilinear form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T(xy)=0$ for all $y\in K$ then $xy$ is in the kernel of $T$, which cannot be the whole of $K$ since $T$ is a non-zero linear map. If $x\neq 0$ then $xy/x=y$ is also in the kernel of $T$, for all $y\in K$. This is a contradiction, so $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, there is one more question concerning this bilinear form; I showed that the sequence $x_n=T(\alpha^n)$ is the output of a linear feedback shift register of length $d$. The period of $x_n$ is the least integer $r$ s.t $x_{n+r}=x_n$ for all large $n$, but why does the sequence $x_n=T(\alpha^n)$ has period $2^d-1$ now?

Comment: I don't know what a linear feedback shhift register is, but the answer to your question probably lies in the fact that $\alpha$ generates the unit group $K^*$ which is of order $2^d-1$. This means that the powers of $\alpha$ constitute all non-zero elements of $K$ and that $\alpha^{2^d-1}=1$, after which the powers repeat their values, i.e. $\alpha^n = \alpha^{(2^d-1)\cdot \ell +n} ~\forall n \in \mathbf{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in K$ so that $\forall y\in K, T(xy)=0$

Let $z\in K$ so that $T(z)\not=0$ (which exists because $T\not=0$)

Suppose that $x\not=0$

Since $K$ is a field, $x$ is invertible

By taking $y=x^{-1}z$, you get $T(z)=0$ which is absurd

So $x=0$

Comment: Thanks, there is one more question concerning this bilinear form; I showed that the sequence $x_n=T(\alpha^n)$ is the output of a linear feedback shift register of length $d$. The period of $x_n$ is the least integer $r$ s.t $x_{n+r}=x_n$ for all large $n$, but why does the sequence $x_n=T(\alpha^n)$ has period $2^d-1$ now?

Comment: @Alkibiades: the period of that sequence depends on the choice of $\alpha$. It has full period only, if $\alpha$ is a primitive element. That would IMHO be best treated in a separate question.